# using numpy and matplotlib, I get ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to create a resulting image from a sample of images:

```
sample_list = [tiff.imread(img) for img in sample]
avg_img = np.mean(sample_list, axis=0)
```

Where `avg_img` is the numpy array resulting from the average of the *n* images contained in  sample.

When I run the code  `plt.show(avg_img`) to display the resulting image, I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I would like to know why I get the above error

Comment: Try using `plt.imshow` instead of `plt.show`.